What would happen if all the matter and antimatter in the universe annihilated?
Assuming matter and antimatter in the universe are in equal amount, if they would annihilate,would the universe be left filled only with photons, resembling the state of the early universe? Furthermore, is it theoretically possible for these photons to converge at a single point, and if so, could this trigger a new Big Bang-like event?

If it all annihilated, there wouldn’t be any more Universe to make predictions about. And no, not all photons could converge since in an annihilation reaction two photons are produce moving in opposite directions, and we’ve also insodoing destroyed every mirror in the Universe.

"What if" questions like that tend to be very open ended unless you do more research yourself in order to focus the issue. For example, if you think that in such a hypothetical scenario a new "Big Bang" event can be triggered, explain based on what you're offering that possibility. Also see discussion on "what if's" on Meta

@controlgroup, but don't photons affect spacetime, if photons, could affect spacetime then the trajectory could change. And also the interaction of photons with the quntum foam.

Photons affect spacetime at extremely high density. The resulting energy density of the Universe would (necessarily) be exactly the same as before annihilation, so no new spacetime curvature. If they don’t all start out moving the same direction, then they can’t all collide at a single point without something to reflect them.

Note that the Big Bang didn't happen at a single point. It happened everywhere. See Did the Big Bang happen at a point?

Assuming matter and antimatter in the universe are in equal amount… Whoa! Don’t assume that, because it isn’t true. As Wikipedia explains, “There is strong evidence that the observable universe is composed almost entirely of ordinary matter, as opposed to an equal mixture of matter and antimatter.”

It's usually problematic to answer a what if question when the "if" is so far from reality.
There a problems: where's the 1/2 of antimatter coming into existence? Are we just randomly flipping 1/2 of it, for a uniform mixture? Then stars and planets explode instantly.
Nebula...idk, what is the mean free path of interstellar gas?
Note that electron/positron annihilation is dominated by 2 and 3 photon final states, so they're mostly making gammas. With so many reactions you're going to probe the rarer events, though. Any number of photons is possible.
Baryon/antibaryon annihilation is a little different. You're going straight to mesons, which eventually weak decay through muons to electrons (and positrons), which will also annihilate. It will make lots of neutrinos, though.
The baryons are going to be hot. A neutron star w/ half antineutrons...I am reticent to estimate the temperature, but:
$$ E = 10^{33}{\rm g/mol}\times N_A \times m_Nc^2 $$
is a big number. Around a kilo FOE.

Ordinary particles make up about 5% of the universe. The rest is dark matter and dark energy. We don't know enough about these to say whether or not there is anything with which they could annihilate.
As for ordinary matter, something like what you suggest already did occur. In the very early universe, matter and antimatter were present in very nearly equal amounts. There was a 1 part per billion excess of matter. The rest annihilated, leaving the matter we see. The matter-antimatter asymmetry problem
